# Simple date time conversion error unresolved for 24 hrs convert.todatetime error

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-services

I have two string `date = "20/04/2016"` and `time = "01:18:58 AM"` when I try to add its working fine in local but when I deploy the application it is giving error.

```
DateTime StDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date + " " + time);
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.    at
>   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>   DateTimeStyles styles)    at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)

DateTime dt=DateTime.Now; just need to change the time for this to "01:18:58 AM"

Comment: What is the error exactly? `FormatException`?

Comment: string not recognized as a valid datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your local machine and your deployment machine has different culture settings since `Convert.ToDateTime` method uses [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) settings if you don't supply any `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter.

Either you should should *equalize* your culture settings based on your local culture, or use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) method to specify your string format with a proper culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
DateTime StDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20/04/2016 01:18:58 AM",
                                      "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you wanna *always* get current date with those time parts, you can parse your time parts to DateTime so their date parts will be the current date.

```
var starttime = "01:00:00 AM";
var endtime = "05:00:00 AM";
var startTimeDATE = DateTime.ParseExact(starttime, "hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 20.04.2016 01:00:00
var endTimeDATE = DateTime.ParseExact(endtime, "hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 20.04.2016 05:00:00
```

Now you can insert those `startTimeDATE` and `endTimeDATE` to your sql server directly with preferable a parameterized query.

Comment: i have tried this but its always giving error. or else can you please help me to just change time part of a datetime

Comment: @Tan No, this won't throw any exception. [Here a demonstration](http://ideone.com/k8vetY) What do you mean by _just change time part of a datetime part_ exactly? Do you want to parse to your `time` to `DateTime` with current date as a date part?

Comment: i have two times starttime="01:00:00 AM" and endtime=="05:00:00 AM" of a day. i have DateTime dt= DateTime.Now; (This will give 20/04/2016 03:00:00 AM for example) i just need to change the time part of datetime to startTimeDATE="20/04/2016 01:00:00 AM" endTimeDATE="20/04/2016 05:00:00 AM" so that i can pass this to sql to retrieve data

Comment: @Tan Updated my answer based on your comment. Take a look.

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem my service is deployed to client. thank you and thanks stackoverflow